# Free voice chat program ubuntu through proxy

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any free ubuntu or linux application for voice-chat over internet connected through proxy?

Need an application suggestion for voice-chat with friends over internet which

- should be able to connect to internet through proxy
- should work on ubuntu
- should be free software

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically, name your requirements (must-haves, must-nots, and nice-to-haves). We like specific questions and specific answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few voice over IP (VOIP) programmes for GNU/Linux:

- Ekiga
- Empathy (the default on Ubuntu I believe)
- Linphone

And a few more, but these are the 'main' ones.

Here's a screenshot of Ekiga:
[image]

Here's Empathy:
[image]

And here's Linphone (link): [Linphone Screenshot](http://www.linphone.org/assets/images/Screenshot%20Desktop%202.png)

They all support using a proxy. I've always used Ekiga, but recently tried out Linphone as it has apps for Android, Blackberry, iOS, Windows, etc. making it a little easier for friends and family who I've not yet managed to encourage onto GNU/Linux.

All are available in the Ubuntu software repos, so installing them is as simple as:

```
sudo aptitude install ekiga empathy linphone
```

Comment: Empathy is not working fine through proxy

Comment: I think with Empathy you may need to configure the global proxy settings through Network Manager. Alternatively you can install `tsocks` with `sudo aptitude install tsocks`, configure the `/etc/tsocks.conf` config file for your proxy, then launch Empathy with `tsocks dbus-launch empathy`. Although if either of the other two are ok, it may be easier to use one of those :)

Comment: thaaaaaaanks (needed 15 chars :) )